# Same column family name in different Hbase tables

Tags: hbase

Can we have same column family name in two different tables in HBase and 
how the data is stored in this case?

Comment: have you tried to create 2 tables with same column families ? its basic that its possible

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to have the same column family name in different tables as they will be stored in different files in HDFS.

See more in [official documentation](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#columnfamily)

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible since

Tables are split into chunks of rows called “regions”. Those regions are distributed across the cluster, hosted and made available to client processes by the RegionServer process

A Region in turn, consists of many “Stores”, which correspond to column families
and there are different splits for each columnfamily

Data in the hfiles inside the splits are store in the form of

```
key=123
columnfamily=s
columnIdentifier=AS1,AS2,BT1
Timestamp = 1476864522000
values will be in the form of byte array =33 0 31 30 30 31 33 33 34 34 35
```

Raw Datadump of a Hfile

```
keyvalues={123/s:AS1/1476864522000/Put/vlen=1/seqid=0,
123/s:AS1/1476862406000/Put/vlen=1/seqid=0, 
123/s:AS2/1476862406000/Put/vlen=1/seqid=0, 
123/s:AS2/1476862406000/Put/vlen=1/seqid=0, 
123/s:BT1/1476864522000/Put/vlen=3/seqid=0}
```